# Сервер отправил куки, но браузер их не установил

Tags: node.js, webpack, frontend, xampp, port

У меня есть веб приложение на React.js, которое лежит на сервере `webpack devserver` и есть бэкэнд, который лежит на сервере `xampp`. Вебпак работает на порту `9000` (`http://127.0.0.1:9000`), а xampp на 80 (`http://my-server.loc`). Я делаю запрос с фронта и в ответ сервер бэкэнда присылает мне куки. Это видно во вкладке Network.

**Response Header от my-server.loc**

[image: Response Header от http://my-server.loc]

Но если после этого посмотреть все принятые куки, то от `my-server.loc` нет ничего. Хром просто проигнорировал куки в ответе сервера из-за чего не работает авторизация.

**Куки, установленные на 127.0.0.1:9000**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такого поведения раньше не было. На браузерах FireFox и Edge куки принимаются нормально и авторизация работает.

**Что пробовал?**

Выяснилось, что Хром по каким-то причинам не принимает куки на сайты, у которых порт не равен 80 (в моем случае я использую 9000). Настроил фронт на порт 80, а бэкэнд на 9000, но проблема осталась. Хрому видимо нужно чтобы и тут и там было 80;

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему Хром так себя ведет? Раньше такого не было.
2. Можно ли заставить Хром все-таки принимать куки не смотря на порт?
3. Если вышеперечисленное невозможно, есть ли способ запустить сервер вебпака и xampp одновременно на порту 80?
4. Любые другие варианты решения...?

**Конфигурация вебпака:**

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src",
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

**UPD 0:** куки от различный метрик ставятся без проблем (возможно потому что они ставятся из js)

Comment: Гуглить third party cookies

Comment: @AlexeyTen в Хроме отключена блокировка сторонних кукисов. Кст, если поключить любую метрику, то сайт спокойно принимает куки с доменов метрики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение найдено!** (как всегда там, где даже не подумаешь смотреть).

Видимо я когда-то давно включил флаг в хроме `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` и с каким-то новым обновлением хрома они что-то поломали (переделали) и сайт не принимал куки. Я проверил несколько раз - когда флаг выключен все работает, когда включен - ничего не работает.